# How to add client_credentials token to Spring Cloud Gateway backend request?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'd like my Spring Cloud Gateway to connect to the backend via a Keycloak serviceuser account using a client_credentials workflow.

My idea was to write a GatewayFilter that enhances the request by an access token. I already did this with an ordinary webclient, but I'm stuck with the filter framework, as none of the interfaces seems to match.

This is how far I got:

```
 @Component
    class ServiceUserTokenFilter(
        private val clientRegistrationRepository: ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
        private val clientService: ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService,
    ) : GatewayFilter {
    
        private var oauth = ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager()).also {
            it.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("keycloak")
        }
    
        override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: GatewayFilterChain): Mono<Void> {

           // help!    
                
        }    
    
        private fun authorizedClientManager(): ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager {
            val authorizedClientProvider = ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider()
            val authorizedClientManager = AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, clientService
            )
            authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider)
            return authorizedClientManager
        }
    
    }
```

With a WebClient I would do `WebClient.builder().apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration()).build()`

How do I use the ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction with the ServerWebExchange/GatewayFilterChain?